# Fetching friend count from specific user PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, https, facebook-php-sdk

So I'm not the best PHP programmer out there and I'm trying to figure out how to get friend count from specific facebook profiles without logging in.

I've done the same thing for youtube which just requires a file_get_contents command and then you can get the subscriber count from the JSON.

Is there any similar way to do it with PHP? Been looking at the facebook PHP SDK but it's pretty difficult for me to understand exactly what I should do. I have a registered developer account I just need to know how to fetch the data and what to use as an identifier for an account. On youtube there are names and ID's that can be used. In facebook you often have a name + a number afterwards just like facebook.com/john.smith.43.

The basic idea is that I want you to be able to give the php code a name and then it just gives you back how many friends that person has.

Comment: Not possible. The user would have to log in to your app and grant it permission before you can access that information. Plus, access to user objects via username is not possible any more, that field has been removed with API v2.0

Comment: That's weird that it doesn't work then. Shouldn't it work if I use my own access token?

Comment: For your own user account ... yes. For anybody else's - of course not.

Comment: Well for me that's not an "of course" thing. If I'm logged in to my account and visit random facebook pages on my browser I can see total amount of friends for a lot of users.

Comment: But thanks for the help anyways ! :)

Comment: UI and API are different things. For a good reason - whatever info you as a friend see about me on Facebook, is the info I have decided to share with you. Now let's have an app come into play - and suddenly this is not between the two of us any more, but a 3rd party has entered the playing field: The app developer. Now in this special case here you might be playing both roles - but for the majority of apps and use cases, that is not the case. So if that app wants _my_ data, _I_ have to agree to it; that is not a decision you can make on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

May be this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/get-friends-list-using-facebook-api-with-php-script/ works for you....